# Join two named lists, keep .x if duplicate

Tags: r, purrr

I want to join/append/combine/merge two named list, `listA` and `listB`, into one list (`listComplete`). If element is in both lists, keep one and discard the other.

Let

```
listA = list(a = 'a', b = 'b')
listB = list(a = 'a_FromListB', c = 'c')
```

Then I want to join/combine these two to

```
listComplete = list(a = 'a_FromListB', b = 'b', c = 'c')
```

I have tried using `c`, but this repeats all elements. I have read that `base::append` is just a wrapper around `c`, and for some reason I get error on `purrr::append`(does not exist in namespace -  I'm using purrr 0.3.2). I have also tried `purrr::list_modify`, but this "nests" `listB` to element `a` in `listA`:

```
purrr::list_modify(listA, listB )
$a
$a$a
[1] "a_FromB"

$a$c
[1] "c"


$b
[1] "b"
```

It is important to

- keep only element `a` from `listB`,
- not nest lists,
- keep all other (disjoint) elements.

A bonus is to order the new list such that it starts with `listA` (where all elements that also is in `listB` is replaced with values in `listB`) then `listB`.

I know I can write my own function, but this seems to be something that should be out of the box - especially from `purrr`.

Comment: Do you need `c(listA, listB)[!duplicated(c(names(listA), names(listB)), fromLast = TRUE)]`

Comment: Aahh!! Thank you! I didn't know about `duplicated( , fromLast)`. Nice!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `duplicated` on the concatenated `names` of both `list`s and then use this to filter out the elements in the concatenated `lists`

```
c(listA, listB)[!duplicated(c(names(listA), names(listB)), fromLast = TRUE)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way :

```
c(listA,`[<-`(listB, names(listA), value = NULL))
#> $a
#> [1] "a"
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "b"
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] "c"
```

Answer (score 0):

A general function for any number of lists:

```
list.merge = function(...){
  args = list(...)
  x = args[[1]]
  for (arg in args[2:length(args)]){
    for (name in names(arg)){
      x[[name]] = arg[[name]]
    }
  }
  return(x)
}
```

It's probably slow, but does work for the edge cases of empty lists, and only one argument, e.g. `list.merge(list(),list(a=1))` and `list.merge(list(a=1))`.

It also preserves the order of duplicate elements as they appear in early arguments, e.g. `list.merge(list(a=1,b=2),list(a=2))` yields `list(a=2,b=2)` not `list(b=2,a=2)`.